# How do I switch from implementation to compile in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, compilation, apk

I also need to update a couple of tools, but it says everything is up to date... Trying to compile Mycroft AI Core, then Mycroft AI Client APKs... Here is the git repo: [Mycroft-Android-Core](https://github.com/MycroftAI/MycroftCore-Android)[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFn2S.png) [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aICk.png)

Here are a my gradle files... All that I found. I'm not sure what else to do.

::Build.gradle file::

> ```
>     // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
> buildscript {
>     ext.kotlin_version = "1.2.51"
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>         maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
>         maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
>         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
>         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
>         classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
>
>         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>         // in the individual module build.gradle files
>     }
> }
>
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>     }
>
>     ext.versionMajor = 1
>     ext.versionMinor = 0
>     ext.versionPatch = 1
>     ext.versionClassifier = "SNAPSHOT"
>
>     project.ext {
>         versionCode = ext.versionMajor * 10000 + ext.versionMinor * 100 + ext.versionPatch
>         versionName = getVersionName()
>     }
> }
>
> task clean(type: Delete) {
>     delete rootProject.buildDir
> }
>
> String getVersionName() {
>     String versionName = "${ext.versionMajor}.${ext.versionMinor}.${ext.versionPatch}"
>     if (ext.versionClassifier != null && !ext.versionClassifier.isEmpty()) {
>         versionName = versionName + "-" + ext.versionClassifier
>     }
>     return versionName;
> }
>
> subprojects {
>     project.configurations.all {
>         resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
>             if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
>                     && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
>                 details.useVersion "$rootProject.supportVersion"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> ext {
>     minSdkVersion = 19
>     targetSdkVersion = 27
>     compileSdkVersion = 27
>     buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
>     kotlinVersion = "1.2.51"
>     supportVersion = "27.0.1"
>
>
> ::Build.Gradle (for **Mobile**)
>
>
>     // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
> buildscript {
>     ext.kotlin_version = "1.2.51"
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>         maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
>         maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
>         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
>         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
>         classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
>
>         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>         // in the individual module build.gradle files
>     }
> }
>
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>     }
>
>     ext.versionMajor = 1
>     ext.versionMinor = 0
>     ext.versionPatch = 1
>     ext.versionClassifier = "SNAPSHOT"
>
>     project.ext {
>         versionCode = ext.versionMajor * 10000 + ext.versionMinor * 100 + ext.versionPatch
>         versionName = getVersionName()
>     }
> }
>
> task clean(type: Delete) {
>     delete rootProject.buildDir
> }
>
> String getVersionName() {
>     String versionName = "${ext.versionMajor}.${ext.versionMinor}.${ext.versionPatch}"
>     if (ext.versionClassifier != null && !ext.versionClassifier.isEmpty()) {
>         versionName = versionName + "-" + ext.versionClassifier
>     }
>     return versionName;
> }
>
> subprojects {
>     project.configurations.all {
>         resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
>             if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
>                     && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
>                 details.useVersion "$rootProject.supportVersion"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> ext {
>     minSdkVersion = 19
>     targetSdkVersion = 27
> compileSdkVersion = 27
> buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
> kotlinVersion = "1.2.51"
> supportVersion = "27.0.1"
> ```

::Build.gradle **Mobile**

> ```
>     /*
>
>          *  Copyright (c) 2017. Mycroft AI, Inc.
>          *
>          *  This file is part of Mycroft-Android a client for Mycroft Core.
>          *
>          *  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
>          *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>          *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
>          *  (at your option) any later version.
>          *
>          *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
>          *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>          *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
>          *  GNU General Public License for more details.
>          *
>          *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>          *  along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
>          *
>          */
>         apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>         apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
>         apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
>         apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
>
>         android {
>
>             compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
>             buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
>             defaultConfig {
>                 applicationId "mycroft.ai"
>                 minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
>                 targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
>                 versionCode project.ext.versionCode
>                 versionName project.ext.versionName
>                 testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>             }
>             buildTypes {
>                 release {
>                     minifyEnabled false
>                     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>                 }
>             }
>
>             dataBinding {
>                 enabled=true
>             }
>         }
>
>         repositories {
>             google()
>             jcenter()
>             maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
>         }
>
>         dependencies {
>             implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
>             implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
>             implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportVersion"
>
>             implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportVersion"
>
>             // layout deps
>             implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
>             implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
>
>             implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$rootProject.supportVersion"
>
>             // Unit test dependencies
>             testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
>             testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
>             testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:1.6.4'
>             testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.4'
>             testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'
>             testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>             // Instrumentation dependencies
>             androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
>             androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
>             androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportVersion"
>             implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') {
>                 transitive = true
>             }
>             implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.4.0'
>             wearApp project(':wear')
>             implementation project(':shared')
>             //kotlin
>             implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
>             //rxjava,rxandroid
>             implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.3'
>             implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
>
>             implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
>
>             implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$rootProject.supportVersion"
>         }
> ```

```
::Build.gradle **Watch**::
```

> /*
>        *  Copyright (c) 2017. Mycroft AI, Inc.
>        *
>        *  This file is part of Mycroft-Android a client for Mycroft Core.
>        *
>        *  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
>        *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>        *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
>        *  (at your option) any later version.
>        *
>        *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
>        *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>        *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
>        *  GNU General Public License for more details.
>        *
>        *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>        *  along with this program.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
>        *
>        */
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
>
> android {
>
>     compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
>     buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId 'mycroft.ai'
>         minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
>         targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
>         versionCode project.ext.versionCode
>         versionName project.ext.versionName
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
>     productFlavors {
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
>     compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0'
>     implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0'
>     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:16.0.1'
>     implementation project(':shared')
>     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
> }
> ```

Comment: The message says that a newer version of the libraries is present. Just press Alt+Enter keys and Android Studio will update those libraries for you. Sync the project afterwards and you will be good to go.

Comment: **ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.** There's also this...

Comment: please upload your gradle file.

Comment: I don't see a way to do that... Would you like the log info?

Comment: Edit your question and copy-paste your app.gradle file